# panelOnDestroyCallback does not work in Mobile

Tags: tasks, mobile, force-recorddata

I have a `Aura component` with form for creating a standard Task object using `force:recordData`.
And I want to use `panelOnDestroyCallback` in order to navigate to Lead object in mobile version.
However I am not sure ?
Is `panelOnDestroyCallback` method supported by mobile version of salesforce ?

Any advices and help will be appreciated.

Thank you.